# Custom Blog Archive Page in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, customization, archive

What I want to do is have a page that lists all of my posts, ten at a time, paginated and starting with the most recent (first page shows 10 most recent posts, with links to skip to the next/oldest/etc. 10 posts). And I want each post on the list to display: the title, the date, an excerpt, and a "Learn More" button. Of course, that means styling each archived post in a div. Here is a screenshot of how I have it styled in my html prototype:

https://plus.google.com/105168282869678130658/posts/hMxABrRqKDf

Here is how the div is structured (the CSS styles work just fine, so I won't bore you with that):

```
<div class="storyPreview">
   <h2>[TITLE OF POST]</h2>
   <p><em>[DATE OF POST]</em></p><br>
   <p>[EXCERPT FROM POST]</p><br>
   <a class="learnMore" href="[LINK TO POST HERE]">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

And here is my archive.php, so far:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Archives
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <main role="main">
        <!-- section -->
        <section>

            <h1>News &amp; Blog Archive</h1>


        </section>
        <!-- /section -->
    </main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Is this possible? Is it going to require super-sophisticated PHP ninjitsu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I must have found just the right search term, because I figured it out! Here is what I used in archive.php:

```
<main role="main">
    <?php $args = array(
    'numberposts'     => 10,
    'offset'          => 0,
    'orderby'         => 'post_date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true ); ?>

    <?php $posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>
    <!-- section -->
    <section>

    <h1>News &amp; Blog Archive</h1>
        <?php if ($posts_array) : ?>

            <?php foreach ($posts_array as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <?php
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format());
                ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
         <?php else : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php next_posts_link('View Older Entries') ?>


    </section>
    <!-- /section -->
</main>
```

BUT...there's one last issue, feel free to comment if you know (otherwise, I'm sure I can find the answer, eventually): the next_posts_link is not working; nothing shows up. I currently have 11 posts, so another page should become available, right?

Comment: Okay, so I figured out (using an if/else) that the next_posts_link wasn't showing up because the page is not recognizing any older posts beyond the tenth. Commenting-out the 'numberposts' line doesn't do the trick, either. How do I get the older posts to paginate, using this code? Can I?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress can do this for you to some extent.  If you really want to personalize it, connect to the database that stores the posts (order by the date like you mentioned) then build a view template that writes the title and summary for each blog entry using a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is very doable, without being a php whiz (I'm going to assume you've got at least some basic programming knowledge).

Let's start by understanding how Wordpress generates the pages. In your case, you want an archive. Your archive.php page will look to create individual posts, in my preferred case, it will look for the file content.php to find what to spit out. You can see more on the hierarchy [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

So it goes `archive.php` -> `content.php`.

### Archive.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Archives
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <main role="main">
        <section>
            <h1>News &amp; Blog Archive</h1>

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) :?>

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
                    <?php
                        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format());
                    ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php else : ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'archive' );?> 
            <?php endif; ?>
        </section>
    </main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'll explain what each part does

- `if ( have_posts() ):` This checks whether there are posts to display. If there isn't it'll display a **no-results.php** page instead.
- `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` This will loop through all your posts
- `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format());` Shows the actual post, checks for the file **content.php**.
- `get_template_part( 'no-results', 'archive' );` Displays the **no-results.php** page if no posts are found.

So now you've got `archive.php` looking for `content.php`.

### Content.php

You might have to restyle, I've used an article (which contains post information) to wrap the outside of your div.

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Generate
 */
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> itemprop="blogPost" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" itemscope="itemscope">
    <div class="storyPreview">
       <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
       <p><?php the_time('jS F Y'); ?></p><br>
       <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p><br>
       <a class="learnMore" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Learn More</a>
    </div>
</article>
```

Should be a bit more self-explanatory, but I'll explain them anyway:

- `the_title()` Retrieves and displays the title of the post *you may want to wrap this in a link to the post*.
- `the_time('jS F Y')` Gets the time in a specific format. You can learn how to change the format [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_time)
- `the_excerpt()` Shows an excerpt of the post. If you're using custom post types then you can define your own excerpt to be shown, otherwise it just shows words up to a certain point from the post.
- `the_permalink()` This is the generated link to your post.

I can't guarantee that all of this will work right off the bat, but it should be enough to at least get you going.

Comment: Wonderful! It's almost there! But, for some reason, it's only showing one "post": the News & Blog page. So basically, the while loop is only showing one page--itself--instead of the 11 test posts I added.

How do I get it to show posts instead of a link to the page itself? Thanks again.